# how can I make that two elements among themselves same height?

Tags: html, css

How can I make two different elements among each other in html same height using css?
I have tried to solve it using in the css 50vh per element but it doesnt work.

codepen: https://codepen.io/ichfickedeinemutterdudummerwichser/pen/vYpwGJv

```css
body {
  background-color: #404040;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#welcome-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #8FBC8F;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: strong;
}

.nav.links {}

a {
  color: grey;
}

#projects {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Titel</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <div class="nav-links"> <a href="#about">about</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#projects">projects</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#contact">contact</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    </div>
  </nav>
  <section id="welcome-section">
    <h1>Hey I am Silvan</h1>
    <h2> a web developer</h2>
  </section>
  <section id="projects">
    <h1>these are some of my projects</h1>
    <iframe />
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you also use HTML and are willing to show us here a "minimal but complete" example of your code?

Comment: `<div style="display: flex"><span class="item-1"></span><span class="item-2"></span></div>` uses [`align-items: stretch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) by default.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mre] and consider updating your original post with a working code snippet so that we can see what CSS classes you're using and your HTML structure. We need something to pick apart if we are to assist you :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

use display flex

```
parent { 
   display: flex;
}
child1, child2 {
   flex: 1;
}
```

both childs will take 50% of the parent's width and height

main is parent, sections are childs

```
<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
  </nav>
  <main>
     <section id="welcome-section">
     </section>
     <section id="projects">
     </section>
  </main>
</body>

main{ 
   display: flex;
}
section {
   flex: 1;
}
```